# Powershell search registry content in event log

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for some code to search the registry content of a log file. Specifically:

```
Get-ItemProperty -path hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\enum\usbstor\*\* | select PSChildName
```

would list the serial numbers. For each of the serial numbers, I need to be able to search the text log file to see when the item appears.

Here is what I'm using now:

```
Get-ItemProperty -path hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\enum\usbstor\*\* | select PSChildName | foreach-object {Get-Content C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log | select-string '$_.PSChildName' -context 1}
```

But the search for `PSChildName` is not working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think its cause of the | is not sending any thing through the $_.PSChildName . So you could use 1 of 2 solutions

Solution 1

```
Get-ItemProperty -path hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\enum\usbstor\*\* | select PSChildName | foreach-object {$P = $_.PSChildName ; Get-Content  C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log | select-string $P -SimpleMatch -context 1}
```

Solution 2

```
$KeyListArray = @()
    Foreach($key in Get-ItemProperty -path hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\enum\usbstor\*\* | select PSChildName)
    {$KeyListArray +($key)}


foreach($PsChild in $KeyListArray)
{Get-Content C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log | select-string -Pattern "$PsChild" -context 1}
```

Comment: Ok glad to help,please can you mark it as answered.What solution will you be using 1 or 2